# sql Group by does not work on selecting multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query

```
SELECT  ACTIONFINANCIALTRANSACTIONLOG.ID_CSE,
        ACTIONFINANCIALTRANSACTIONLOG.DTE_PROC
FROM CSESDEV02.FINANCIAL_TRAN_LOG ACTIONFINANCIALTRANSACTIONLOG 
GROUP BY ACTIONFINANCIALTRANSACTIONLOG.ID_CSE  
HAVING COUNT(TXT_DESC) > 9
```

this results in

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
> 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error at Line: 57 Column: 47

however, if i select only 1 column , it works

```
SELECT  ACTIONFINANCIALTRANSACTIONLOG.ID_CSE
FROM  CSESDEV02.FINANCIAL_TRAN_LOG ACTIONFINANCIALTRANSACTIONLOG 
GROUP BY ACTIONFINANCIALTRANSACTIONLOG.ID_CSE  
HAVING COUNT(TXT_DESC) > 9
```

why is that?

Comment: the reason is "DTE_PROC" is not part of aggregation nor part of group by .

Comment: You certainly like to make things hard on yourself with those overly long table names and alias names!

Answer (score 3):

Although there's no aggregate function in `SELECT` column list, all columns that aren't aggregated should be part of the `group by` clause.

If there are `2` columns you're selecting, both have to be part of the `group by`.

---

BTW, table alias should be **short** so that it "simplifies" query and makes it easier to read. You did the opposite.

---

This is what works OK - only one column in `select` and it is part of `group by`:

```
SQL> select deptno
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  having count(job) > 1;

    DEPTNO
----------
        30
        20
        10
```

This doesn't work: two columns in `select` list, only one in `group by`:

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2         ename
  3  from emp
  4  group by deptno
  5  having count(job) > 1;
       ename
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

But, when they both are in `group by`, query is OK:

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2         ename
  3  from emp
  4  group by deptno, ename
  5  having count(job) > 1;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html).

**Gist:**

> SelectItems in the SelectExpression with a GROUP BY clause must
> contain only aggregates or grouping columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because GROUP by require all the column defined in SELECT clause.

The SELECT statement used in the GROUP BY clause can only be used contain column names, aggregate functions, constants and expressions.

select count(1),deptno
from emp
group by deptno
having count(1) > 1;

Answer (score 0):

`ACTIONFINANCIALTRANSACTIONLOG.DTE_PROC` is not the product of a summary function and is not mentioned in the GROUP_BY clause so you get the error you've gotten. Perhaps you could use:

```
SELECT ftl.ID_CSE,
       ftl.DTE_PROC
  FROM (SELECT af.ID_CSE,
               COUNT(af.TXT_DESC) AS TXT_DESC_COUNT
          FROM CSESDEV02.FINANCIAL_TRAN_LOG af
          GROUP BY af.ID_CSE
          WHERE COUNT(af.TXT_DESC) > 9) iq
  INNER JOIN CSESDEV02.FINANCIAL_TRAN_LOG ftl
    ON ftl.ID_CSE = iq.ID_CSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax aside, think about the aggregation group you are defining with your `group by` clause:

```
GROUP BY ID_CSE
```

means you want one row per `ID_CSE`. Examples would be average salary per department, total sales per region, vaccinations per country.

In that **one row** for each `id_cse`, what `dte_proc` should be displayed if there is more than one distinct value?

For example, say your data contains

```
ID_CSE DTE_PROC
------ ----------
1      X
1      Y
2      Z
```

Now if you query

```
select id_cse, date_proc, count(*) from financial_tran_log
group by id_cse
```

what results do you expect to see?

```
ID_CSE DTE_PROC COUNT(*)
------ -------- --------
1      ???             2
2      Z               1
```

It can't be done, hence the syntax error.